# Use a google sheet to show file updates on google drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Maybe this is already known, or there is a better way if you know please tell me.
I want a google spreadsheet that shows me the last updated file on each folder on googledrive.  and that it upgrades itself if new folders or files are added.

For example, i have a main Folder, the spreadsheet should tell me about updates subfolders A B C D

Folder name, lastfileupdatedname in that folder , Who updated it and when.

Comment: Take a look at [Google Drive Activity API](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2)

Answer (score 1):

Since asked specifically about apps-script; two options come to mind:
Advanced Google Services\Google Drive Activity Service [ Google Drive Activity API in Apps Script]

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive-activity

or

use a folder/file iterator
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator